# Adding dependency of another project into Spring MVC web project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, artifactory

I my Spring MVC web project I have two parts of project.

1. Core Part : which contains all the model class, services class and some utility classes.
2. Web Part : which contains controllers, views, resources, XMLs etc.

Both project in single workspace and having their own pom.xml.

To use any class from core part in web part what I am doing is, I am exporting core project as JAR selecting only `src/main/java` then importing the JAR as `an artifact to a  Maven repository`. The same process I have to do if any small change occur in core part.

Is there any way to minimize the step for exporting as JAR and re-deploying as an artifact to a  Maven repository.

*I have tried this:*

As my core part's pom says it is already creating an artifact: (Image below of core part's pom)

[image]

So I tried with adding that artifact in my web project and its got added but as I run my project I got `HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception` error. looks like web application is not referring to core JAR at runtime.

Comment: I think you should use Maven Plugin. I am not using this but [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/) maybe usefull for you

Comment: Are you providing the dependency scope of core package? your web project is compiling it means it is having the dependency however it is not available at runtime means it is not getting included in war.

Comment: The HTTP 500 message doesn't tell anything of what went wrong. Please post a stacktrace.

Comment: @apurvc, Yes dependency scope is set to default i.e `compile`. Do I need to change it?

Comment: @Amogh no compile means the jar will be included. If you are running the project in eclipse check your {wtp.deploy}/{project}/WEB-INF/lib directory for your core jar is getting included. Eclipse sometime has issues deploying/re-deploying a webapp.Refer arguments tab of eclipse of run configuration for deploy directory.

Comment: @apurvc, I checked `WEB-INF/lib` its not having core jar.

Comment: Are you running your project in eclipse? check my previous comment.

Comment: @apurvc, in argument tab VM arguments are : `-Dcatalina.base="D:\Softwares\springsource3\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\base-instance" -Dcatalina.home="D:\Softwares\springsource3\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\tomcat-7.0.30.A.RELEASE" -Dwtp.deploy="D:\Softwares\springsource3\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\Softwares\springsource3\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE\tomcat-7.0.30.A.RELEASE\endorsed" -Xmx768m -Xss192k -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dinsight.enabled=false`

Comment: So go to D:\Softwares\springsource3\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEA‌​SE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\{your project}\WEB-INF\lib and manually add the core jar. Your web project should run fine. Consider that when you create the war of your web-app it will work or manually create the war of your web-project it should have the core jar in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @apurvc Manually adding JAR on desired location is same as deploying JAR into artifactory which is I m currently doing.

Comment: dude manually create a war or by using maven package command, your war mostly should have the core jar in WEB-INF/lib. eclipse sometimes doesn't copy the jar in deployed directory deleting the project location and re-publishing might work for you.